# Why custom validator in Meteor SimpleSchema is being called twice?

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

Code:

```
Event = new Mongo.Collection('event');

var eventSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    custom: function() {
      console.log(this.field('name').value);
    }
  }
});

Property.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
    check(doc, eventSchema);

    return true;
  }
});
```

Then the event name is being printed twice in the terminal.

Any ideas to prevent that?

Comment: you don;t show how/where you attach the schema, and the Collection names don't event match so hard to say, but in short the schema is evaluated every time you request it so it will prompt the console log on the `check` call and any call to register it, use it etc...